# Scalable <textarea> with custom shapes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What should I do if I wanted to create a textarea with the shape of a speech bubble - like what you would see in a comic - or a thought bubble that expands as it needs to when text is entered into it?

EDIT:

Hey guys, sorry for not being clear enough with my question before - though I did get some useful responses altogether. If there was a way to give two people the 'Checkmark' points I would because two people did answer my ambiguous question.

I am not opposed to using JS, but the link someone recommended actually does pretty close to what I need, with that being said, the first response also gave me a nifty idea. Since the posts that would have the custom wrapper would have a maximum character length, I could perhaps just come up with three different sizes of the same styling and have them be used depending on the length of the post.

Anyways, thanks guys for your great input!

Comment: Most (read - if you make your own browser then you'll be able to decide if you need them round or square or 3D) browsers restrict textareas to rectangular shapes, but you _can_ draw anything around it to make it look like a speech bubble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qugibuba/2/edit)**

AFAIK `textarea` is not meant to listen to content-change and resize respectively
(not without JS) so this is my best suggestion so far:

[image]

```
<span class="bubble" contenteditable="true">Type here</span>
```

```
.bubble{
  position:relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ff9;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color:#000;
  border:2px solid #000;
  border-radius:20px;
  outline:0;
}
.bubble:after{
  content: ' ';
  position:absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:-10px;
  width:15px;
  height:15px;
  background:#ff9;
  border-right: 2px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a website that could help you to do what you're asking. 
**[CSS Text Wrapper](http://www.csstextwrap.com/)**

Comment: Great link! Totally am using this

Comment: Glad to help. I have learned (and still learning) so much from that site.

Comment: Alas, it appears to be no more. The perils of link only answers

Answer (score 1):

try a borderless textarea with a background matching the background color of a background image you will need to have.

e.g. you have a div wrapping the textarea. that div has rounded corners to make a circular shape (e.g. width: 100px; border-radios: 50px; background-color: white). the textarea must not have border, and must have the same bg color, and of course must be centered.

that's just a tip, there are many other implementations.